# How InverseTransformPoint work in Unity3D

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine

I want to create a function in C++ that will calculate **InverseTransformPoint** similar to Unity3D InverseTransformPoint function.
Documentation says

> it transform position x,y,z from world space to local space.

I am getting **position (x,y), orientation** of a vehicle and a target **position (x,y)** to follow. I can't calculate InverseTransformPoint in unity. I can only Update orientation of a chasing car based on given parameters.

Comment: InverseTransformPoint code is hidden you have to make additional payment in pro or enterprise license in order to access its source code.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with matrix calculations. I don't remember the exact thing but, to convert a local space to world space, you have to multiply it by a world matrix, so to do the inverse method, I guess you would have to multiple the world space position with the inverse of the world translation matrix.